# Attach the current user to the request with bearer strategy in passport azure ad

Tags: passport.js, bearer-token, passport-azure-ad

I have a NodeJS API server using express and passport for authentication. I am using the passport azure ad bearer strategy for authentication with Microsoft Azure AD. In the examples provided in the documentation(https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapi/blob/master/node-server/app.js#L50), the owner (currentUser) is a javascript variable defined globally. How do I attach the user to the request so that I can do something like

```
server.post('/user', passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', {
    session: false
}), function(req, res, next){
    console.log(`I am the current user ${req.user}`);
});
```

From the example mentioned in the OIDC strategy, I have seen a `deserializeUser` and `serializeUser` function that would allow the user ID to be stored in the session, However, in the bearer strategy, we do not have any sessions maintained as authentication will be performed for every incoming request.

This may be a gap in my understanding. I have gone through the documentation for the individual libraries. Please help me if there is a way this can be done

Answer (score 0):

Following is the sample code via which you can embedd the yser object to request object . Thus when you will do `${req.user}` in post callback you will get the user object

```
const BearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy;
var bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(options,
      function(token, done) {
        findById(token.oid, function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
            return done(err);
          }
          if (!user) {
            // "Auto-registration"
            return done(null, token);
          }
          const owner = token.oid;
          return done(null, user, token);
        });
      }

);
```

Comment: When I try this I get `ReferenceError: findById is not defined`

Comment: findById will be a custom function implemented by the developer of the app , which will contain the customizable business logic .

Comment: That wasn't clear to me, thanks for pointing that out. I'm still learning how it all fits together.